# Restart SonarQube Server remotely

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I implemented `SonarQube` on the server, and I do most of the configurations **remotly**. Hence whenever a plugin is installed, a restart of `SonarQube` is required and every time I have to **explicitly (manually) restart the `SonarQube` server**.

***Is there a way to restart `SonarQube` remotely?***

*For example, like `jenkins` through `http://sonar_url/restart`.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since SonarQube 5.4, you can restart it directly from the UI ([Administrators should be able to request a server restart from web console](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-1976)) or using the WS /api/system/restart ([WS /api/system/restart should trigger a true restart of SQ](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7168)).

Comment: Hi Alexandre, is there a bug or a problem with this functionality? I can't restart the server by pressing that button, I get the popup saying that the page will be refreshed, but nothing happens. My SonarQube server stops replying (hangups). To get it back working the only solution is to restart the service. I'm referring to a SonarQube instance running on Windows.

Comment: If you're using SonarQube 5.4 or 5.5, you should upgrade to 5.6, the issue has been fixed : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7422

Comment: Also `Administration` -> `System` -> `Restart Server`

Comment: cannot find ```Restart Server```

Answer (score 1):

> POST api/system/restart 
>   Since 4.3 Restart server. 
>   Available only on development mode (sonar.web.dev=true). 
>   Ruby on Rails extensions are not reloaded

Regards,

Michel

Answer (score 1):

In my SonarQube instance (v5.6), I use the below curl command to restart SonarQube server

```
curl -u username:password -X POST https://SONAR_INSTANCE/api/system/restart
```